# How to tell optuna which parameters to optimise

Tags: python, optimization, xgboost, hyperparameters, optuna

```
import optuna
import xgboost as xgb

import sklearn.datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

def objective(trial: optuna.Trial, X, y) -> float:

    params = {
        "colsample_bytree": trial.suggest_float('colsample_bytree', 0.2, 1.0),
        "subsample": trial.suggest_float('subsample', 0.2, 1.0),
        "max_depth" : trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 2, 24),
        "min_child_weight" : trial.suggest_int('min_child_weight', 0, 10),
        "colsample_bylevel" : trial.suggest_float('colsample_bylevel', 0.2, 1.0),
        "colsample_bynode" : trial.suggest_float('colsample_bynode', 0.2, 1.0),
    }

    model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params)
    
    score = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3).mean()
  
    return score



iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
X, Y = iris.data, iris.target

study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize',sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(seed=10))
study.optimize(lambda trial : objective(trial,X, y),n_trials=50)
```

In the code above I want to perform some xgboost hypermarameter tuning using optuna.
My question is: How can I pass to the objective functions which parameters to optimize without changing the objective function?

for example: In case I want to optimize only `max_depth` I thought about passing an extra parameters as

```
entries_to_remove = ["colsample_bytree", "subsample", "min_child_weight",
 "colsample_bylevel", "colsample_bynode"]
```

and delete the entries in the dictionary in the objective

```
def objective(trial: optuna.Trial, X, y, entries_to_remove) -> float:

    params = {
        "colsample_bytree": trial.suggest_float('colsample_bytree', 0.2, 1.0),
        "subsample": trial.suggest_float('subsample', 0.2, 1.0),
        "max_depth" : trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 2, 24),
        "min_child_weight" : trial.suggest_int('min_child_weight', 0, 10),
        "colsample_bylevel" : trial.suggest_float('colsample_bylevel', 0.2, 1.0),
        "colsample_bynode" : trial.suggest_float('colsample_bynode', 0.2, 1.0),
    }
    for k in entries_to_remove:
        del params[k]

    model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params)

    score = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3).mean()

    return score



iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
X, Y = iris.data, iris.target
entries_to_remove = ["colsample_bytree", "subsample", "min_child_weight",
     "colsample_bylevel", "colsample_bynode"]

study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize',sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(seed=10))
study.optimize(lambda trial : objective(trial,X, y, entries_to_remove),n_trials=50)
```

However this does not work and all the parameters are optimised anyway

Comment: What about other parameters? Should they be fixed for some random values, or "best so far", or one you provide? Why is it problem to create new study with new objective function?

Comment: The other parameters can be the default values. The problem is that I would like to use the same objective function in different problems and in each problem I need to optimise certain parameters depending on the task.

Comment: But this will never be the same objective function if you change a thing in it like choosing which parameters to optimize. For each problem use different "version" of the objective function you have, substitute "trial.suggest.." to fixed values where you want

Answer (score 1):

In this case Optuna is not actually optimizing the parameters in the `entries_to_remove` but it thinks as it does.

As each line with `"XXX" : trial.suggest_XXX()` executes(and it will execute since it is in the dictionary declaration), the given parameter and the range will be saved to the `distributions` attribute of the trial object to keep track of the parameters to optimize, and a value will be assign to the left side object according to given parameters. Of course these objects will be deleted in the next loop and will not be passed to the model itself, so the model will be build according to the default values for the deleted parameters. But the trial object will still have the same parameters in its `distributions` attribute which will make the program act as if these parameters are still being optimized.

To resolve this issue you should make sure that the parameters are not declared with `trial.suggest_XXX()` if they are not going to be optimized. A possible solution would be using if statements:

```
params= {}
if "colsample_bytree" not in entries_to_remove : params["colsample_bytree"] = trial.suggest_float('colsample_bytree', 0.2, 1.0)
if "subsample" not in entries_to_remove : params["subsample"] = trial.suggest_float('subsample', 0.2, 1.0)
```